# Time limit exceeded using Scanner - Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, time-limiting

I'm testing this code in Java with a [problem from a programming Judge](https://www.jutge.org/problems/P72986_en) and I get a "time limit" error. I guess the *scanner.hasNextDouble()* thingy is not working somehow.

It works with the public inputs shown in the link but it throws this time limit error with the privates.

Any idea to solve this issue?

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

class Main /*AvalPoli2*/ {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US); // dot sep.
        nf.setGroupingUsed(false); // don't group in groups of 3 
        nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(4); 
        nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(4);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        scanner.useLocale(Locale.US); // read doubles with dot separator
        double sum = 0.0000;
        double x = 0;
        if (scanner.hasNextDouble()) x = scanner.nextDouble();
        while (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
            sum *= x;
            sum += scanner.nextDouble();
        }
        System.out.println(nf.format(sum));
    }
}
```

Thank you very much! ^_^

Comment: Wrap System.in in a suitable BufferedInputSomething?

Comment: What error / exception do you get?

Comment: No exception or error, looks like the loop never ends or the program waits for input forever.

Comment: But it works with the inputs shown in this link, and matches the outputs: https://www.jutge.org/problems/P72986_en (ignore security warning, university SSL is not verified)

The problem is with the inputs that are not shown, they are more challenging.

Answer (score 1):

You have to Wrap your System.in, like

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
in = new Scanner(br);
```

instead,

```
in = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Reader class by yourself, here is my Reader class code.

```
/** Reader Class */
static class Reader {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer("");

    /** Get next line text */
    String next() throws IOException {
        while (!tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(reader.readLine());
        }
        return tokenizer.nextToken();
    }

    int nextInt() throws IOException {
        return Integer.parseInt(next());
    }

    double nextDouble() throws IOException {
        return Double.parseDouble(next());
    }
}
```

To use this class, you need to create an object(assume it named reader).
To get a int number, you should `reader.nextInt()`.
To get a Double number, you should `reader.nextDouble`.